# toplevel: Undefined procedure Prolog

Tags: prolog, sudoku

sudoku(X,Board):-

```
Board=X,

Board =
[A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,
     B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,
     C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,
     D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,
     E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9,
     F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,
     G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,
     H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,
     I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9],

    %rows on the board
permutation([A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),

%columns on the board
permutation([A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3,H3,I3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A5,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A6,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A7,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A8,B8,C8,D8,E8,F8,G8,H8,I8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A9,B9,C9,D9,E9,F9,G9,H9,I9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),

    %each individual box will be a permutation of 9 different numbers
permutation([A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A4,A5,A6,B4,B5,B6,C4,C5,C6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([A7,A8,A9,B7,B8,B9,C7,C8,C9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([D1,D2,D3,E1,E2,E3,F1,F2,F3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([D4,D5,D6,E4,E5,E6,F4,F5,F6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([D7,D8,D9,E7,E8,E9,F7,F8,F9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([G1,G2,G3,H1,H2,H3,I1,I2,I3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([G4,G5,G6,H4,H5,H6,I4,I5,I6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
permutation([G7,G8,G9,H7,H8,H9,I7,I8,I9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
```

the above is solve/2
5 ?- solve(X,Y).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: solve/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

that happened when I tried with 2 normal variables

2 ?- solve(X,[*,7,2,4,*,_,*,*,1,*,8,*,7,*,*,3,2,*,6,3,1,*,_,*,7,*,_,*,*,_,5,2,*,*,1,4,*,*,5,9,*,4,6,*,_,8,4,*,*,3,7,*,*,_,*,*,9,*,*,_,2,5,3,*,6,8,*,_,5,*,7,*,2,*,*,_,*,9,4,6,*]).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: solve/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

the same happened when the 2nd variable I input was a list with some fixed numbers

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong and it's really getting frustrating trying to think of possible answers when nothing's working
Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant

```
solve(X,Board):-
  Board = X,
  Board =
    [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,
     B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,
     C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,
     D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,
     ...
```

but I think your code will be too slow to work...

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that I wasn't calling the function by it's right name -.-
And you're right it is too slow to work, guess I should re-define my rules

Comment: The main problem it's that constraints are unrelated. Instead of permutation/2, you could attempt to use select/3, a 'poor man' substitution for all_different. But my advice it's to study the awesome code from [library(CLPFD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.7%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpfd.html%27%29%29), search there for sudoku.

Answer (score 2):

Error says that `solve/2` is not defined.

I can't see definition of `solve/2` in the code you provided. Is it all the code you have?

`solve/2` is not a special or built-in predicate, you have to define it if you call it.